# get data from input box and insert to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This code from Google API. I want to get value from search box "pac-input" then insert to mysql database. How can I get value from input box? I already tried `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` but did not work
This is the source:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" name="pac-input">
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

  function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);



    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB9RRjfBs5H4kP7Pa-1SePt6FzrzmC6KX8&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
     async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST` would work only after form submission. If you want to access the value of the input field before that, you can directly do `input.value`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the input "pac-input", use the following command in javascript:

```
var search_box = document.getElementById('pac-input').value;
```

Comment: how can I add that var search_box to PHP variable. Thanks

Comment: You can do it this way:

Send a request via ajax, which is the most recommended:

or

    `<script type="text/javascript"> var search_box = document.getElementById('pac-input').value; </script>`

.And in php put the following code: 

    `<?php
    $variavelphp = "<script>document.write(search_box)</script>";
    echo "Olá ".$variavelphp;
    ?>`

Comment: when I did that, php echo "object HTMLInputElement"

Comment: yes I did that after declaration of javascript code